# Form not posting all inputs of a form after the .append()

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, forms, codeigniter

My form submitting input field fine without appended input field. When I append input field by clicking add button and input value there and submit my form my appended data not posting.

I tried to print comments after post submit.

```
 function edit($id,$redirect=false){
    if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
    {
         $data = array( $save['comments'][] = json_encode($this->input->post('comments')) );
            print_r($data);

      //echo $save['comments'] =  json_encode($this->input->post('comments')); 
      exit();
   }
 }
```

My output

```
Array ( [0] => ["test"] )
```

But it just displaying 1st comment not from next that I added using javascript.

```js
$(function() {
        var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
        var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
        $('#addScnt').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        
         $(scntDiv).append('<p><input type="text" name="comments[]" class="form-control col-md-10"/><a href="#" id="remScnt"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true"></i>remove</a></p>');
         i++;
       
                
        });
     $(document).on("click", '#remScnt', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
         if( i > 2 ) {
                        $(this).closest('p').remove();
                        i--;
                }
              // return false;
     });
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/observation/edit/'.$id.'/'.$redirect)?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_form">
 
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="comments[]" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label>
    </p>
</div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary update">Update</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: For starters your html is invalid. `<p>` can't be a child or descendant of another `<p>`

Comment: @charlietfl ok now I updated my question.

Comment: I used json_encode and just echo that but it's just displaying first comment but not displaying next comment which I input from appended html.

Comment: have you checked by firebug that element (your field) adding successfully?

Comment: @RejoanulAlam thanks for comment. Here is the video link I am facing.http://www.screencast.com/t/ammbtyZhNKeh

Comment: As an exercise try changing `print_r($data);` to `print_r($this->input->post());` That will show you everything posted.

Comment: @DFriend this is the result Array ([comments] => Array ( [0] => test) ) appended input field not passing value.

Comment: I built a test case from your code and it works for me. My only thought is that somewhere in your view html there is bad markup i.e. open tags or somesuch. I will post the exact code I used in an answer if you like.

Comment: @DFriend Yes that was closing tag bug. generraly I checked code from  [this tool](http://www.aliciaramirez.com/closing-tags-checker/) but not found that bug. But after checking line by line code I found that. Thanks. now code working fine.